# ngClass in ionic 3 not working correctly

Tags: angular, ionic3

I've been trying for hours to get this done but it's not working.

What i'm trying to do is just changing the sandwich icon using a smooth rotate animation when the menu opens to an arrow icon and the opposite when the menu closes.

here are 3 of the components involved in the example.

header.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

import { HomePage } from '../../pages/home/home';

@Component({
    selector: 'th-header',
    templateUrl: 'header.html',
    animations: [
        trigger('rotateToLeft', [
            state('closed', style({
                transform: 'rotate(0deg)'
            })),
            state('opened', style({
                transform: 'rotate(180deg)'
            })),
            transition('opened <=> closed', animate('200ms ease'))
        ]),
        trigger('rotateToRight', [
            state('opened', style({
                transform: 'rotate(0deg)'
            })),
            state('closed', style({
                transform: 'rotate(-180deg)'
            })),
            transition('closed <=> opened', animate('200ms ease'))
        ])
    ]
})
export class Header {
    isOpen: boolean = false;
    menuState: string = 'closed';

    constructor(public events: Events) {
        this.events.subscribe('menu:opened', () => {
            this.isOpen = false;
            this.menuState = 'opened';
        });
        this.events.subscribe('menu:closed', () => {
            this.isOpen = true;
            this.menuState = 'closed';
        });
    }

    goToHomePage() {
        this.events.publish('root_page_changed', HomePage)
    }
}
```

header.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar >
        <ion-buttons text-center [ngClass]="{'sandwich': !isOpen, 'arrow': isOpen}">
            <button ion-button menuToggle>
                <ion-icon name="menu" [ngClass]="{'hide': isOpen}" [@rotateToLeft]="menuState"></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon name="arrow-round-back" [ngClass]="{'hide': !isOpen}" [@rotateToRight]="menuState"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title text-center>
            <img class="max-width" src="assets/imgs/header-logo.png" (click)="goToHomePage()">
        </ion-title>        
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

I tried everything but when i get to the HomePage (where the header is) the arrow icon is shown along with the menu icon, even though the [ngClass] is done properly and the variable is declared with the right value.
You can also see the subscription to the menu events, I debugged the code and it does stop there and the values of the variables do change, but the ngClass never applies the classes to the elements.

Here is the menu.ts where I publish the events for opening and closing the menu.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

import { CreatePage } from '../../pages/create/create';
import { SearchPage } from '../../pages/search/search';
import { TraysPage } from '../../pages/trays/trays';

export interface PageInterface {
    name: string;
    component: any;
    title: string;
    iconName: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'th-menu',
    templateUrl: 'menu.html'
})
export class Menu {
    @Input()
    navContent: any;

    constructor(
        public events: Events
    ) {}

    pages: PageInterface[] = [
        { name: 'create-page', component: CreatePage, title: 'Crear Documentos', iconName: 'new-icon' },
        { name: 'search-page', component: SearchPage, title: 'Buscar Documentos', iconName: 'search-icon' },
        { name: 'trays-page', component: TraysPage, title: 'Bandejas', iconName: 'trays-icon' }
        // { title: 'Create', component: CreatePage }
    ];

    pageSelected(page) {
        this.events.publish('root_page_changed', page.component);
    }

    menuOpened() {
        this.events.publish('menu:opened');
    }

    menuClosed() {
        this.events.publish('menu:closed');
    }
}
```

here's the menu.html

```
<ion-menu [content]="navContent" enabled="false" (ionOpen)="menuOpened()" (ionClose)="menuClosed()">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list inset>
            <button menuToggle ion-item *ngFor="let page of pages" (click)="pageSelected(page)">
                <img src="assets/imgs/icons/{{page.iconName}}.png">
                <span>{{ page.title }}</span>
            </button>
            <button menuToggle ion-item>
                    <img src="assets/imgs/icons/logout-icon.png">
                    <span>Cerrar Sesión</span>
                </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

And here is the home.html where I include the header element

```
<th-header></th-header>

<ion-content padding class="th-bg-content">
    <div class="home-content">
        <div class="box-container vertical-center">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img class="max-width" src="assets/imgs/logo-blue.png">
            </div>
            <div class="text-container" text-center>
                <h3>Líder en soluciones para la gestión digital.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="link-container" text-center>
                <a href="http://vivatia.com">www.vivatia.com</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Any ideas why it is not working ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try the following implementation

`[ngClass]=" isOpen ? 'sandwich': 'arrow'"`

is a bit more clear, also if it does not work I recommend you to print the value on screen to see which value is the variable taking like:

`{{isOpen}}`

EDIT:

Also you could simplify the syntax a bit more, to avoid getting this kind of problems, like you could use the same event and send a parameter. I personally don't like abusing of the ionic events. You could use `@Output` and `@Input` to update `isOpen`, or if menu is a child of header, then you could use `@ViewChild()`.

Example:

```
menuOpened() {
    this.events.publish('menu:toggle', {status: true});
}

menuClosed() {
    this.events.publish('menu:toggle', {status: false});
}
```

and subscribe:

```
this.events.subscribe('menu:toggle', (status) => {
        this.isOpen = status;
    });
```

Comment: The value is right when the component is rendered for the first time but in this part:

    `<ion-icon name="menu" [ngClass]="isOpen ? 'hide' : ' ' " [@rotateToLeft]="menuState"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-round-back" [ngClass]="isOpen ? ' ' : 'hide'" [@rotateToRight]="menuState"></ion-icon>`

it's not taking any effect in this part, the two icons still show up.

Comment: I tried everything but still no results at all. I don't how to do this with this ionic version, with ionic 1 it was way easier and always worked the way it's supposed to.

Comment: I have an idea , why don't you update isOpen inside ngZone?